# How to share the screen output of a running process?

Tags: bash

I have a program that will run for a long time , This program edit and run in remote server .I use 
the computer in office to remote connect the server and run it . The progress shows on the computer screen of the computer in my office ...

I want to see the output in my home , How can I capture the output which is on the screen of computer in office and see the result at home?

I think about writing the output to a file , but I need to close the file . So I should open file then write output , close .. open again?

thanks

I don't know the proper tag should use , but the program is written in perl .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `tee` it

```
your_program.pl | tee logfile.txt
```

and see the lastest result in `logfile.txt` at home with

```
tail -f logfile.txt
```

Comment: Note that you should probably capture stderr along with stdout

Comment: Exactly. It could be done with `your_program.pl |& tee logfile.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just redirect to a log file and [tail](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tail.htm) it (or load it in an editor etc.) ?

```
$ myprog.pl >/tmp/logfile 2>&1
```

The above redirects your output to a log file (`/tmp/logfile` - you may wish to choose a better location since `/tmp` is temporary and can be trashed during a reboot) and redirects stdout/stderr to the same place. Note that this captures the *output* of your program and you don't need to modify your script.

An alternative is to run your program within [screen](http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Use-The-Gnu-Linux-Screen-Terminal-Window-Manager.htm)

> Perhaps one of the most useful features is that you can re-connect to
>   your sessions after you log out, move to another computer, or get
>   disconnected, and continue working as if nothing happened. All your
>   edit sessions, shell windows, etc. will be there just as you left
>   them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use `screen` for this sort of thing.

- Connect to the server
- Enter the command `screen`.  It displays a nice message stating the version of `screen` and that it's under the GPL.
- Run the actual command.
- At any time, hit `ctrl-A`, `D` to disconnect from the `screen` session.  You'll see a message along the lines of `[detached from pid.tty.server]`.  Log out from the server normally.
- Connect to the server again and enter the command `screen -x` to reconnect to your session.